# C++ no viable constructor copying variable of type

Tags: c++, c++11, implicit-conversion

I am getting the following error message:

*main.cpp: No viable constructor copying variable of type 'communal'*

On the second constructor,`communal( const T& instance )`, the following message is given:

*data.h: Candidate constructor not viable: no known conversion from 'communal' to 'const int &' for 1st argument*

The conversion appears to be going backwards.  I want the conversion to go from const int& to communal.  Is there a way to get implicit conversion to work here?  Thanks for any help.

**main.cpp:**

```
communal<int> test_communal1 = 123; // Implicit initialization triggers error
```

**data.cpp:**

```
template<typename T>
struct communal : general_type::communal<T>
{
    using super = general_type::communal<T>;

    communal() : super( nullptr ) {}
    communal( const T& instance ) : super( new T( instance ) ) {}
    communal( const T* instance ) : super( new T( instance ) ) {}
    communal( communal<T>& instance ) : super( instance ) {}
    communal( communal<T>* instance ) : super( instance ) {}

    ~communal()
    {
        this->counter->deallocate( [this]()
        {
            delete this->counter;
            delete this->instance;
        });
    }
};
```

Comment: That's not the error message I get: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/70f71efbc2b2666c
"error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type 'communal<int>&' to an rvalue of type 'communal<int>'"

Comment: Thanks @MooingDuck, I am going to try this without the inheritance to see if the error message is the same or gone.  I use a 3 layer inheritance which may be having some strange effect.  If you find any reason for this, I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks again @MooingDuck.  I think I am going to rephrase this question and minimize it to focus on the problem of creating a converting constructor.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the solution to this.  My intention was to get the following converting constructor to work `communal( const T& instance )`.  I made the mistake of leaving off const for my copy constructors.  For some reason, it was deducing to use the faulty copy constructor along with potential conversion from `communal<int>` to `const int&`.  In adding const to the constructor, it fixed the problem.  Though, it does seem to be a bug that it would not prioritize using the converting constructor first.  Maybe with more studying this problem, I could get a deeper understanding to why it prioritized the other constructor over the converting constructor.  Though, that will have to wait for now.